# How to allow a user to login with user_name or email using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to give users the ability to sign-in using either their unique `user_name` or the email address they input while registering.

Session_Controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
  @user = User.where(username: params[:username]).first if @user.nil?

  if @user && @user.password == params[:password]
   session[:user_id] = @user.id
   flash[:notice] = "Successfully Logged In #{ @user.fname }"
  else
   flash[:alert] = "Your credentials do not match the database"
  end
  redirect_to "/users/#{ @user.id }"
 end
```

User_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @users = User.all
  current_user
  if @current_user
    @leaders = @current_user.leaders
  end
 end

 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
   flash[:notice] = "Signup Complete"
  else
   flash[:alert] = "Unsuccessful Signup"
  end
  redirect_to "/users"
 end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :email, :password, presence: true # validates_presence_of :email
 validates :password, length: {in:6..10}
```

Login page:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<%= form_tag('/sessions', method: "POST") do %>
 <%= email_field_tag(:email, "", placeholder: "email") %>
 <%= password_field_tag(:password, "", placeholder: "password" ) %>
 <%= submit_tag("Login") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `email_field_tag`, use a `text_field` tag.  That way, the user won't have to deal with client-side email validation when logging in via username.  Then change your parameter name accordingly (e.g. `username_or_password`, instead of `email`).

In your controller, you can use this parameter for both queries:

```
@user = User.where(email: params[:username_or_password]).first
@user = User.where(username: params[:username_or_password]).first if @user.nil?
```

Alternatively, you could attempt to determine whether or not the parameter is an email address by parsing the string - that way, you would not be executing two separate queries whenever someone tried to log in with a username.

Comment: You could skip 'if @user.nil?' if you just use ||= in that line instead of =