# How can I allow users to sign in using their email or username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've spent days looking for this, I made a username table when creating my users and realized later in the project that I didn't need to have that but instead just let them use the email. I've tried different things with no luck. PLEASE NOTE: I am NOT USING DEVISE. I do not want to use Devise either. Here is my code, Thanks in advanced if you can help me out! And no this is not the same question as another because I read that one and did what the correct answer said to and no luck.

This is users_controller.rb,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :signed_in_after_register, only: :create 

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @user = User.search(params[:search])
  end

  def dashboard 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end 

  def newsfeed
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == nil
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end

  def nav
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
  def posts
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end

  def welcome
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new(params[:post_id])
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully created!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def signed_in_after_register 
      session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :name, :bio, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :age, :profile_picture, :post, :body)
    end
end
```

Here is my Model for user.rb,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, :first_name, :last_name, :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true 
  validates_inclusion_of :age, in: 10..100
  validates :password, presence: true 
  has_many :posts
  has_attached_file :profile_picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
  :default_url => "app/assets/images/missing.png", 
  :path =>  ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename" 
  validates_attachment_content_type :profile_picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

This is my _form.html.erb,

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<div class="sign_up_form_2">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :age, placeholder: "Age", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Password Confirmation", class: "form-control" %>
  </div><br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bio %>
    <%= f.text_area :bio, placeholder: "Write something!", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :profile_picture %>
    <%= f.file_field :profile_picture %><br>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create Account", class: "btn btn-default btn-sign-up" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
</div>
```

This is in my sessions_controller.rb,

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :checked_logged_in, only: :login 
  def login

  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
    if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id 
        redirect_to dashboard_path
    else 
        redirect_to login_url, notice: "Invalid User or Password Combination"
    end

  end

  def destroy
    if session[:user_id]
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to login_url

    end

  end
  private 

  def checked_logged_in 
    if session[:user_id]
      redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: "You are already logged in"

    end

  end
end
```

Just in case here is my gemfile,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby' 

gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'imagemagick-identify', '~> 0.0.1'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'

group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I'm willing to explain any further if needed, I'm also willing to post any more code you may need to see to help me out! Thank you for your time!

Comment: You might want to look at [the rails basic auth guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow a user to login with user\_name or email using Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929897/how-to-allow-a-user-to-login-with-user-name-or-email-using-rails)

Comment: I had read that one Sculper but no luck on my end so I figured I'd ask myself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SessionsController#create change this line:

```
user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
```

to this:

```
user = User.find_by(name: params[:name]) ||
       User.find_by(email: params[:name])
```

Or some other variant that looks at both fields:

```
user = User.where(["name = ? OR email = ?", params[:name], params[:name]]).first
```

You could also check `params[:name]` and if it has an '@' in it, look it up by email, otherwise by username.

Comment: Thanks so much man! I am going to rate your answer as correct! It means a lot, The 3rd line of code you gave me to try didn't work though but the other two did user = User.find_by(name: params[:name]) ||
       User.find_by(email: params[:name]) so thank you!

Comment: @genobambino Just noticed a missing `]` in that third line.  It should work as well now.